Propensity score Matching: how to decide if prioritise balance or sample size
I tried different methods (nearest with or without replacement, optimal, full, genetic) to perform PSM between two groups using the MatchThem package. Eventually, I identified two models that perform well: one in which all variables are balanced but some cases are excluded, and another (full model) in which one variable is slightly unbalanced, but all cases are retained.
NEAREST LOGIT
# Perform matching in each imputed dataset
m.out_model1 <- matchthem(formula, 
data = new_df_imputed, 
method = "nearest", 
distance = "logit",
replace = TRUE,
ratio = 3,
caliper = 0.2)

Output:
Balance summary across all imputations
                                        Type Max.Diff.Adj    M.Threshold
distance                            Distance       0.0130 Balanced, <0.1
Metastasis_size_at_treatment_mm      Contin.       0.0136 Balanced, <0.1
Segments_treated_per_session         Contin.       0.0336 Balanced, <0.1
Metastasis_location_superficial_Yes   Binary       0.0089 Balanced, <0.1

Balance tally for mean differences
                   count
Balanced, <0.1         4
Not Balanced, >0.1     0

Variable with the greatest mean difference
                     Variable Max.Diff.Adj    M.Threshold
 Segments_treated_per_session       0.0336 Balanced, <0.1

Average sample sizes across imputations
                         0  1
All                  53.   77
Matched (ESS)        26.96 75
Matched (Unweighted) 45.   75
Unmatched             8.    2

FULL METHOD
m.out_full <- matchthem(formula,
data = new_df_imputed,
method = "full",
distance = "mahalanobis")

Output:
Balance summary across all imputations
                                       Type Max.Diff.Adj        M.Threshold
Metastasis_size_at_treatment_mm     Contin.       0.0477     Balanced, <0.1
Segments_treated_per_session        Contin.       0.1179 Not Balanced, >0.1
Metastasis_location_superficial_Yes  Binary       0.0260     Balanced, <0.1

Balance tally for mean differences
                   count
Balanced, <0.1         2
Not Balanced, >0.1     1

Variable with the greatest mean difference
                     Variable Max.Diff.Adj        M.Threshold
 Segments_treated_per_session       0.1179 Not Balanced, >0.1

Average sample sizes across imputations
                         0  1
All                  53.   77
Matched (ESS)        27.47 77
Matched (Unweighted) 53.   77

If I use the first model, I lose power (and my cohort is already small). On the other hand, choosing the second model allows me to retain the entire population, but the two groups are slightly unbalanced. However, I can account for this by including the unbalanced variable in a multivariable logistic regression.
My question is: Is there a way to determine which model is the best choice? Would it be methodologically correct to compute the power associated with each matched dataset to evaluate which model to use?

Your precision is determined largely by the ESS of the smaller group, which is about the same (~27) for the control group in both matching specifications. I would bet this is too small to detect anything but the largest effects. Given that the ESS is so similar, I would go with the one that yields better balance. It is definitely a good idea to do a power analysis before moving forward with a matching method. You can use a power analysis to determine the smallest effect size you can detect with a given power level for a given sample size or what sample size you need to detect an effect of interest with a given power level.
I would also say that with a dataset this small and with so few variables to adjust for, matching is not the best way to adjust for confounding here. Just use g-computation. It is likely that variance greatly outweighs any bias. You can't afford to lose precision due to matching. Matching is not a general-purpose tool to eliminate confounding; it is only appropriate in certain scenarios.

Hi Noah, thank you for your answer. So, to determine the smallest effect size that I can detect with my matched_df, I should use the ESS, right? Why is it better not to use the Matched (Unweighted) values? Thanks for your help!

Matched (Unweighted) is kind of an irrelevant statistic. You need to include the matching weights in the estimation of the treatment effect or else it's like you didn't do the matching at all. For example, with full matching, it is the weights that yield balance, but they also reduce precision. Using the unweighted matched sample size would be like pretending you didn't do any matching at all. So yes, you should use the ESS for power analysis. See also Shook-Sa & Hudgens (2020).

Ok, I got it. Thank you. By the way, I also wrote you an email some days ago. Let me know if it could interest you. Thanks for the paper suggestion!

I saw it but I'm not in a position to reply. I will in the coming week.
